# Prompt for app update when connect to PC

Tags: android

I am looking at a problem where the customer needs to connect his mobile to windows PC where a desktop app should detect the android version and if there is any updates available should prompt the user to update it. If he confirms should push the firmware from the desktop app to the device.

A simple solution may be to push an app into the device using ADB and through that can we trigger an OTA update?

It should work for non rooted device and is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: If there is such an update for a device Android OS on the device will warn the user I think. So why this hassle?

Comment: @greenapps, the thing is we are developing a data wiping solution so whenever we do the wipe, we need to flash the firmware again.